# How to change download filename in struts

Tags: java, download, struts, filenames

At the moment the filename, that I want to download is named "downloadStatistic.html". I want to change it to "whatever-i-want". It's a *.csv File by the way.

Here is the code of my download action:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component("/downloadStatistic")
public class StatisticDownloadAction extends DownloadAction {

@Override
protected StreamInfo getStreamInfo(ActionMapping actionMapping,
                                   ActionForm actionForm,
                                   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                   HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {

    String filepath = httpServletRequest.getParameter("filepath");
    String contentType = "text/comma-separated-values";

    File file = new File(filepath);

    return new FileStreamInfo(contentType, file);
    }
}
```

And that is my struts xml:

```
    <action
            path="/shipmentStatistic"
            name="shipmentStatisticForm"
            scope="request"
            validate="false"
            type="de.logentis.struts.DelegatingActionProxy"
            input="/jsp/statistics/ShipmentStatistic.jsp">
        <forward name="back" path="/menu.html" redirect="true"/>
        <forward name="download" path="/downloadStatistic.html?filepath={0}" redirect="true"/>
    </action>

    <action
            path="/downloadStatistic"
            type="de.logentis.struts.DelegatingActionProxy">
        <forward name="back" path="/shipmentStatistic.html" redirect="true"/>
    </action>
```

Where I can define the filename of the downloaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you try the following:

```
public class DownloadFileAction extends Action{

 @Override
 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws Exception {

  String filepath = httpServletRequest.getParameter("filepath");
  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=statistic.csv");

  try 
  {
    FileInputStream in = 
        new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
    while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1){
     out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
   }
   in.close();
   out.flush();
   out.close();

 }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
 }

 return null;
 }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                         HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

String filepath = request.getParameter("filepath");
File statisticFile = new File(filepath);

byte[] ourArray = new byte[Integer.parseInt(statisticFile.length() + "")];

response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + statisticFile.getName());

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(statisticFile);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

try {
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
        out.flush();
    }
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
return null;
}
```